# Cohomology of complex projective space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hello : I would like to know how to compute the cohomology of complexe projective space : $ H^p ( \mathbb{P}^n ( \mathbb{C} ) , \mathbb{Z} ) $. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the homology spaces $H_p(\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C),\mathbb Z)$ ?

Comment: @girianshiido : no !  <-) . I want to compute it using the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the cohomology *groups*, then the most natural Mayer-Vietoris argument would be the one arising from the standard cell-decomposition of $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)$ that has one cell in each even dimension from $0$ up to $2n$.  That Mayer-Vietoris argument amounts to showing that the cohomology groups can be computed as the cohomology of the cell complex, which is, in this case, really easy because there are no odd-dimensional chains so all the coboundary operators vanish.  (If you want the cohomology *ring*, then, as far as I know, you'd have to work considerably harder to get the multiplicative structure. I'd be interested to see an elementary computation of that.)